# How to check that a file has more than 1 line in a BASH conditional?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I need to check if a file has more than 1 line. I tried this:

```
if [ `wc -l file.txt` -ge "2" ]
then
    echo "This has more than 1 line."
fi


if [ `wc -l file.txt` >= 2 ]
then
    echo "This has more than 1 line."
fi
```

These just report errors. How can I check if a file has more than 1 line in a BASH conditional?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The command:

```
wc -l file.txt
```

will generate output like:

```
42 file.txt
```

with `wc` helpfully telling you the file name as well. It does this in case you're checking out a lot of files at once and want individual as well as total stats:

```
pax> wc -l *.txt
 973 list_of_people_i_must_kill_if_i_find_out_i_have_cancer.txt
   2 major_acheivements_of_my_life.txt
 975 total
```

You can stop `wc` from doing this by providing its data on standard input, so it doesn't *know* the file name:

```
if [[ $(wc -l <file.txt) -ge 2 ]]
```

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax> wc -l qq.c
26 qq.c

pax> wc -l <qq.c
26
```

---

As an aside, you'll notice I've also switched to using `[[ ]]` and `$()`.

I prefer the former because it has less issues due to backward compatibility (mostly to do with with string splitting) and the latter because it's far easier to nest executables.

Comment: ambigueous redirection in your if statement

Comment: @ANSHULGERA: I don't believe there's anything ambiguous about it, it grabs standard input from the `file.txt` file. If yo could provide more detail on *why* you think it's problematic, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 10):

A pure bash (≥4) possibility using `mapfile`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -n 2 < file.txt
if ((${#MAPFILE[@]}>1)); then
    echo "This file has more than 1 line."
fi
```

The `mapfile` builtin stores what it reads from `stdin` in an array (`MAPFILE` by default), one line per field. Using `-n 2` makes it read at most two lines (for efficiency). After that, you only need to check whether the array `MAPFILE` has more that one field. This method is very efficient.

As a byproduct, the first line of the file is stored in `${MAPFILE[0]}`, in case you need it. You'll find out that the trailing newline character is not trimmed. If you need to remove the trailing newline character, use the `-t` option:

```
mapfile -t -n 2 < file.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if [ `wc -l file.txt | awk '{print $1}'` -ge "2" ]
...
```

You should always check what each subcommand returns. Command `wc -l file.txt` returns output in the following format:

```
12 file.txt
```

You need first column - you can extract it with `awk` or `cut` or any other utility of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
if read -r && read -r
then
  echo "This has more than 1 line."
fi < file.txt
```

The `-r` flag is needed to ensure line continuation characters don't fold two lines into one, which would cause the following file to report one line only:

```
This is a file with _two_ lines, \
    but will be seen as one.
```

Comment: @paxdiablo You are correct. Thanks. One could debate whether two lines where the first one ends in a backslash should be considered one line, since that should be defined by the application. But since `wc -l` ignores the backslash it should be ignored here as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with large files, this `awk` command is much faster than using `wc`:

`awk 'BEGIN{x=0}{if(NR>1){x=1;exit}}END{if(x>0){print FILENAME,"has more than one line"}else{print FILENAME,"has one or less lines"}}' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

change

`` if [ `wc -l file.txt` -ge "2" ] ``

to

`` if [ `cat file.tex | wc -l` -ge "2" ] ``

Comment: it stripped the backpacks on me, you need those

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain what this does and how it solves the original quesiton-asker's problem?